# How to generate getters and setters for all field of scala in Intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have a below code

```
class TestData {
  private var name : String = _
  private var age : Int = _
}
```

When I try to generate getters & setters of the above in java class(alt + insert)-> generate-> then It ak for all the available fields and I am able to add for multple fields.

but the same thing I want to achieve in Scala then It doesn't ask for the fields rather it adds getters and setters for the first field.

Googled aot but could find the solution in Intellij.

Comment: Mutable state is discouraged in Scala/Functional programming. In cases where it is necessary it is well hidden from public view. As a consequence setters are rarely if every required. I strongly suggest you reconsider your program design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `var`s in Scala. Keep everything as immutable as possible.

That being said, you could always use case classes instead of normal classes if you *really* want a class with mutable values. Case classes generate getters and setters for you, behind the scenes.

```
scala> case class Person(var name: String, var age: Int)
defined class Person

scala> val p1 = Person("billy", 12)
p1: Person = Person(billy,12)

scala> println(p1)
Person(billy,12)

scala> p1.age = 45
p1.age: Int = 45

scala> println(p1)
Person(billy,45)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, it's highly not-recommended use mutable states in Scala, if you still want to do that, you can do as follows:

```
class TestData (var name: String, var age: Int)
```

There you can create an object and get the value as `object.attribute` and set the value as `object.attribute = desiredValue`

```
scala> val t = new TestData("edward", 12)
t: TestData = TestData@40ce2a1f

scala> t.name
res2: String = edward

scala> t.name = "Josh"
t.name: String = Josh

scala> t.name
res3: String = Josh
```

What you should use instead of classes with mutable variables is a class with unmutable values. Any of this options will be a more scalish-way:

```
class TestData (val name: String, val age: Int)
case class TestData (name: String, age: Int)
```